# ERROR: Transaction not found

Tags: postgresql

I have just found in pg_log some line of this specific error: 
`ERROR:  Transaction not found //some_hash`

error + surrounding lines:

```
2014-06-04 15:08:49 CEST my_user db_name LOCATION:  exec_bind_message, postgres.c:1771
2014-06-04 15:08:49 CEST my_user db_name NOTICE:  00000: Transaction expired
2014-06-04 15:08:49 CEST my_user db_name LOCATION:  exec_stmt_raise, pl_exec.c:3041
2014-06-04 15:08:49 CEST my_user db_name ERROR:  P0001: Transaction not found egcrppnddxt82frc
2014-06-04 15:08:49 CEST my_user db_name LOCATION:  exec_stmt_raise, pl_exec.c:3041
```

I have found this error only in postgres [source code](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/predicate_8h.html). Is it some internal error? When it can occur?

PostgreSQL version:
PostgreSQL 9.3.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, 
compiled by gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 64-bit

It's a comment I have found in the source code:

> /* We check the transaction's database ID for paranoia's sake: if
>   it's in another DB then its xmin does not cover us.  Caller
>   should have detected this already, so we just treat any funny
>   cases as "transaction not found".*/

Comment: I only see that string in a comment, not in an `elog(...)` or `ereport(...)` line. Please edit to show *exact* output of `SELECT pg_version()` and at least one exact unmodified log line showing the error.

Comment: sure, all informations was added

Comment: Weird. The only instances of `transaction not found` (case insensitive) in the REL9_3_2 git tag's sources are in comments. I'm struggling to understand how this can be emitted by Pg, yet it clearly is. Is there any chance you can re-run with `log_min_messages = debug2` and `log_error_verbosity=VERBOSE` set in `postgresql.conf`? That'll provide some useful info, in particular a filename and line number. Comment here after editing so I get notified. BTW, **9.3.2 has a very serious bug in crash recovery and failover** - upgrade to 9.3.4 *urgently*.

Comment: Sure, will change log settings and get back to you. This is dev server, so it's not a problem with 9.3.2, but in production we will start for sure with 9.3.4.

Comment: so not much more, now is: 2014-06-04 11:48:47 CEST my_user db_name ERROR:  P0001: Transaction not found egcrppnddxt82frc

Comment: You should edit that into the question and comment here with @CraigRinger in the comment so he gets a notification :) - Also, is there anything in the log surrounding this that could assist in the debugging? In doubt clear the log, trigger the exception and then post the whole log.

Comment: There should be more lines before/after with "CONTEXT", maybe "DETAIL" etc

Comment: ok, added in post. expired transaction?

Comment: Borys, you must remember to use "@CraigRinger" in your comments to send him the notification. - Anyway, did you check your configuration? Maybe "Transaction expired" means exactly that?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer ok, but why postgres is trying to do anything with transaction that have already expired? and if I could trigger this event I would do it for sure. And why I've got over 5k lines with expired transactions?

Comment: Well, this is a lesson **why you always include the full, exact text of any error messages / error lines without any editing**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your errors are being thrown  by *user defined code* written in PL/PgSQL.

They are not coming from PostgreSQL. That is why the message `Transaction not found` does not appear in PostgreSQL's source code except in comments. You're barking up entirely the wrong tree.

This:

```
2014-06-04 15:08:49 CEST my_user db_name ERROR:  P0001: Transaction not found egcrppnddxt82frc
2014-06-04 15:08:49 CEST my_user db_name LOCATION:  exec_stmt_raise, pl_exec.c:3041
```

shows:

- The `SQLSTATE` is `P0001`, the default code used by `RAISE ERROR` in PL/PgSQL if you don't override it;
- It's being logged from `exec_stmt_raise`, the `RAISE` statement, inside `pl_exec.c`, the PL/PgSQL executor;
- `Transaction not found egcrppnddxt82frc` is a message *from your application*

I would've expected to see more context lines showing the PL/PgSQL procedure name, too, but perhaps in an explicit `RAISE` they're only emitted to the client, not the server error log. I don't remember.

You might be able to locate the culprit with:

```
\x

SELECT * 
FROM pg_proc p 
INNER JOIN pg_language l ON (p.prolang = l.oid) 
WHERE l.lanname = 'plpgsql' 
  AND p.prosrc LIKE '%Transaction not found%';
```

.. assuming that the procedure isn't forming the error from several separate strings or getting it from somewhere else.

This is why you **always include complete, un-edited error messages**. *If you'd just showed the whole error line I could've told you what was going on hours ago*.

Comment: thank you for your full answer. I was sure it was something about postgres.